# Laravel order items in database

Tags: php, database, laravel, model

Hi I am using Laravel and a custom CMS to sync some tags stored in the CMS into a database. This function works fine. However I want to set an order to them numerically when they are inserted into the database and if a new one is synced into the database I want this to be added into the database as the last value i.e if there are 12 items existing the new item will be added as value 12 (as 0 would have been the first value) in the order column. I want this to be done without reseting the existing order values.

This is what I have in my repository:

```
public function sync()
{

    $tags = $this->client->fetchTags('Status');
    $updated = $this->update_tasks($tags);        
    // remove the rest of the statuses
    \Status::whereNotIn('id',$updated->lists('id'))->delete();
}

/**
 * Save any tags to the local DB;
 * @param $tag
 */
public function update_tags($tags)
{


    $return = [];
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $return[] = $tag->id;    
    }


    $local  = \Status::whereIn('cms_tag_id',$return)->get()->toIndexedArray('cms_tag_id');

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        
        if (isset($local[$tag->id]))
        {
            $local_doc = $local[$tag->id];
        } 
        else
        {
            $local_doc = new \Status;
        }
        $local_doc->updateFromCMS($tag);
        $uids[] = $local_doc->cms_tag_id;
    }
    return \Status::whereIn('cms_tag_id',array_unique($uids));
}
```

And then in my model I have this:
Status.php

```
public function updateFromCMS($tag)
{
    $i = 0;
    $this->cms_tag_id = $tag->id;
    $this->cms_tag_name = $tag->name;
    $this->order = $i++;
    $this->save();
    return $this;
}
```

However this adds all the values in the order column as zero which is undesirable, and any new ones that are found are also added in with the value zero. Any ideas how I can get this order to be saved from e.g: 0-100?

### Update

As per instructions from @insanebits I have changed my model to the following:

```
public function updateFromCMS($tag)
{
    $i = Status::orderBy('order', 'DESC')->pluck('order');
    $this->cms_tag_id = $tag->id;
    $this->cms_tag_name = $tag->name;
    $this->order = $i+1;
    $this->save();
    return $this;
}
```

However this now changes the order values on all the rows. i.e. if the highest value is 5 then the value that was 0 will be set to 6 and then everything will have its value increased by 1. Therefore the order that was set is lost. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Because each time you call this method it uses `$i = 0;` at the beginning. You need to retrieve `order` value from database and only then increment

Comment: `$i = ModelClass::where('order')->orderBy('order', 'DESC)` where model class is your actual model you're using

Comment: I mean you need to get biggest relevant `order` value which is stored in your database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83039/discussion-between-insanebits-and-001221).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *don't* need to update the id's and names of existing tags, you should only call `updateFromCMS` for new tags:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {

    if (isset($local[$tag->id]))
    {
        $local_doc = $local[$tag->id];
    } 
    else
    {
        $local_doc = new \Status;
        $local_doc->updateFromCMS($tag); //only for new tags
    }

    $uids[] = $local_doc->cms_tag_id;
}
```

If you *do* need to update the id's and names of existing tags, then add an argument to `updateFromCMS` that tells it whether to change the order or not:

```
public function updateFromCMS($tag,$update_order)
{    
    $this->cms_tag_id = $tag->id;
    $this->cms_tag_name = $tag->name;

    if($update_order) {
        $i = Status::orderBy('order', 'DESC')->pluck('order');
        $this->order = $i+1;
    }

    $this->save();
    return $this;
}
```

And change your `foreach` as follows

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {

    if (isset($local[$tag->id]))
    {
        $local_doc = $local[$tag->id];
        $local_doc->updateFromCMS($tag,false); //don't update order
    } 
    else
    {
        $local_doc = new \Status;
        $local_doc->updateFromCMS($tag,true); //update order
    }

    $uids[] = $local_doc->cms_tag_id;
}
```

Comment: thats great, this is doing what I require. I will reward the bounty when the timer runs out

Answer (score -1):

What if you set the `order` column in your database to be `autoincrement`? e.g. your migration might look like:

```
class CreateStatusTable extends Migration {

    public function up() {
        Schema::create('status', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->increments('order');
            /* ... your other fields ... */
            $table->timestamps();
        }
    }
}
```

That way you wouldn't have to worry about explicitly setting the `order` field in your model, and you know that every time you added a new `Status` to the DB it would always be assigned the next highest integer value.

Alternatively, you could just drop the `order` column altogether and rely on the `id` field which you know is going to be an integer and be incremented sequentially as you add new `Status` rows to the DB.

The only potential drawback I can see to this approach is that if you ever delete a `Status` you will end up with some rows that have non-sequential values for `id` or `order`, i.e. if you had 5 items in the table and you deleted the item with `id = 3` you would end up with 4 items with `id` values of `0, 1, 2, 4`. The order will always be preserved, however, and code like:

```
$statuses = Status::orderBy('id', 'DESC');
```

will always return an array of `Status` objects in the original order that you added them to the DB.